# XDocument wont get Descendants although the chosen one exists

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq

im having kinda trouble with a XDocument create the XDocument parsing an xml returned from a webservice.
Here is the xml

```
<VentaOnlineList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> 
  <VentasList> 
    <VentaOnlineInfo> 
      <ProcessDate>2010-11-01T00:00:00</ProcessDate> 
      <TicketDate>2010-11-01T00:00:00</TicketDate> 
      <DeliveryDate>2010-09-29T00:00:00</DeliveryDate> 
      <DwhLastMonthProcessData>0</DwhLastMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhLastMonthTicketDate>0</DwhLastMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucLastMonthDeliveryDate>0</PsucLastMonthDeliveryDate> 
      <DwhSelectedMonthProcessData>-6.54</DwhSelectedMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhSelectedMonthTicketDate>-6.54</DwhSelectedMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucSelectedMonthDeliveryDate>-6.54</PsucSelectedMonthDeliveryDate> 
      <DwhNextMonthProcessData>0</DwhNextMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhNextMonthTicketDate>0</DwhNextMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucNextMonthDeliveryDate>0</PsucNextMonthDeliveryDate> 
    </VentaOnlineInfo>  
  </VentasList> 
  <Error> 
    <ErrorFlag>false</ErrorFlag> 
  </Error> 
</VentaOnlineList>
```

now, when i try to call the Descendants lets say from "VentaOnlineInfo" it says that its empty.

here is the code

```
XDocument xmlSell = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent); 
        XNamespace nameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";

        var venta = from ventas in xmlSell.Descendants(nameSpace + "VentaOnlineInfo")
                    select new VentaDigital
                    {
                        ProcessDate = (DateTime)ventas.Attribute("ProcessDate"),
                        TicketDate = (DateTime)ventas.Attribute("TicketDate"),
                        DeliveryDate = (DateTime)ventas.Attribute("DeliveryDate")
                    };

        ventasDigitales.ItemsSource = venta;
```

xmlContent its filled with a string that contains the XML.

Somebody knows why it keeps saying that the descendant dont exist?
Any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here.

First, it looks like you put Attribute when you meant Element in the select clause.  Second, you need to include the namespace when getting those Elements.  <strike>Third, you cannot cast to a DateTime you must parse it.</strike> (EDIT: as long as you don't explicitly reference the Element's Value property it will cast)

Here's the code you posted with those issues fixed.  It appears to work for me:

```
XDocument xmlSell = XDocument.Parse(x); 
    XNamespace nameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";

    var venta = from ventas in xmlSell.Descendants(nameSpace + "VentaOnlineInfo")
                select new VentaDigital
                {
                    ProcessDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "ProcessDate"),
                    TicketDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "TicketDate"),
                    DeliveryDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "DeliveryDate")
                };

        ventasDigitales.ItemsSource = venta;
```

Comment: it may be one error, but it still failing. it throws no exception, but it wont fill the datagrid nethier.

Comment: I found some more issues, see my edited answer.  I tried it in LinqPAD and it worked with these changes.

Comment: You *can* cast to DateTime. There's an explicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch them subvalues as elements *and* include the namespace. Here's a short but complete example which works:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()        
    {
        string xml = @"<VentaOnlineList 
                          xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                          xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
                          xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'> 
  <VentasList> 
    <VentaOnlineInfo> 
      <ProcessDate>2010-11-01T00:00:00</ProcessDate> 
      <TicketDate>2010-11-01T00:00:00</TicketDate> 
      <DeliveryDate>2010-09-29T00:00:00</DeliveryDate> 
      <DwhLastMonthProcessData>0</DwhLastMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhLastMonthTicketDate>0</DwhLastMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucLastMonthDeliveryDate>0</PsucLastMonthDeliveryDate> 
      <DwhSelectedMonthProcessData>-6.54</DwhSelectedMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhSelectedMonthTicketDate>-6.54</DwhSelectedMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucSelectedMonthDeliveryDate>-6.54</PsucSelectedMonthDeliveryDate> 
      <DwhNextMonthProcessData>0</DwhNextMonthProcessData> 
      <DwhNextMonthTicketDate>0</DwhNextMonthTicketDate> 
      <PsucNextMonthDeliveryDate>0</PsucNextMonthDeliveryDate> 
    </VentaOnlineInfo>  
  </VentasList> 
  <Error> 
    <ErrorFlag>false</ErrorFlag> 
  </Error> 
</VentaOnlineList>";

        XDocument xmlSell = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XNamespace nameSpace = "http://tempuri.org/";

        var venta = from ventas in xmlSell.Descendants(nameSpace + "VentaOnlineInfo")
                    select new
                    {
                        ProcessDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "ProcessDate"),
                        TicketDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "TicketDate"),
                        DeliveryDate = (DateTime)ventas.Element(nameSpace + "DeliveryDate")
                    };

        foreach (var x in venta)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you do that and you're *still* not getting anything, that would suggest that something odd is happening in your binding.